# Inequalites between a sum of powers and definite integrals

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, summation

Give a convincing argument that the following inequalities are true:

$$\int_0^n \ x^p\mathrm dx \leq  1 +  2^p + 3^p+ ... + n^p \leq \int_0^{n+1}\ x^p \mathrm dx$$

I've been stuck on this for hours, pretty much lost as to how I would go about solving this question. I was thinking maybe I have to convert the first and third terms into limits of Riemann sums and then the solution would be clearer, but I'm not sure how I'd do even that. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: sorry, forgot to include P is any real number greater than 0, and n is a positive integer. So f(x) is definitely increasing.

Comment: If $f$ is an increasing function then $f(k) \leq f(x) \leq f(k+1)$. Integrate this inequality over $[k,k+1]$ to get $f(k) \leq \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x) dx \leq f(k+1)$. Now sum this inequality over $k=1,2,3,\ldots,n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, answer found. I graphed f(x), as well as the summation in the middle. By shifting the graph of the summation over by one unit, its clear that the area of the summation is less than that of the integral of f(x) from 0 to n+1. I think that this suffices as a 'convincing argument'. Thanks all for your help, I'd upvote but I lack the rep to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered graphing $y=x^p$ for $x\in \left[0, n+1 \right]$? Then draw the rectangles to form some upper and lower Riemann sums where your partition is just $(0, 1, ..., n+1)$.

Comment: Yep, I have. From graphing it, its clear that I have to prove that the integral of f(x) from n to n+1 is greater than or equal to the difference between the right-Riemann sum and the integral from 0 to n of f(x). But I don't know how to proceed from there :/ Thanks though.